# Initializing a variable with an dereferenced pointer in initialization list

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, initializer-list

So I am changing some code from C to C++ , so as a result I have to add all constructor destructors for all the structures/classes.

so consider a following mockup structure

```
struct CAddition {
    int x;
    int *foo;
    int y;
    int c;
    int z[3];
    int result() { 
        return x + y; 
    }
    CAddition();
    ~CAddition();
};
```

Now somewhere in an initialization function the variable `y` was initialized with   a value foo was pointing at somewhat like this

```
int func_test(CAddition *temp)
{
    temp->y = *temp->foo;
    return temp->y;
}
```

I already had my doubts because the pointer foo wasnt pointing at anything (or lets say at a garbage memory location) but still I deleted the intilization function somehow I tried to initialize `y` 
in my initialization list as

```
CAddition::CAddition()
    : x(0)
    , foo(nullptr) // can be simply foo() both are the same as far as i know
    , y(*foo)
    , z()
    ,c(result())
{
}
```

and obviously the programmed crashed because foo is a null pointer , my question is , is there some way or work around where I can initialize `y` with dereferenced pointer `foo` so it doesn't crash

P.S I tried calling the func_test and it also crashed because of the same reason because foo is a `nullptr`

```
CAddition test_fun;
add_res = func_test(&test_fun);
```

Comment: No matter what you try, dereferencing a `nullptr` is always undefined behavior, and pretty much a guaranteed crash.

Comment: You should dereference it only after making a check and being sure that it is not null.

Comment: Obviously your original C code _was_ assigning to that pointer somewhere—but maybe you haven’t found that part of the code yet in your translation.